# How does third party system restoration tools keep themselves from getting uninstalled on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

On some computer I used I noticed that every time I rebooted it, it restored all of the changes including documents. After looking around I found out that it's because of some tool named Toolwiz Time Freeze. It asked me for a password in order to disable it which I don't have. I tried to manually uninstall it by deleting all of the files, turning off auto start for the program on Windows settings and stopping all of the processes related to it. I purged the program in every way I know of. After all of that I created an empty file and rebooted the computer. After it booted up I noticed that it deleted the file and restored the tool completely. It made me ask myself how does it work. Why even after purging it completely from the hard drive it still exists on the system? What features of Windows does it taking used of?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Big question: WHY are you trying to circumvent this system? If a computer is setup like that it is usually for a very good reason. (E.g public use computer in a library or school.) If you don't have permission to try to break this you could be in a lot of trouble... Where I live a few years ago a student tried to do this with a school computer running DeepFreeze (a similar tool) so he could install a game. He got expelled from school and charged with vandalism. The charges were dropped, but he still had to find another school that would accept him (in another town 25 miles away).

Comment: @Tonny My school recently got this computer and they don't know the password.

Comment: A gift or purchased 2nd hand computer that wasn't wiped before given to the school? In that case wipe the whole disk and re-install with a fresh Windows image. You should do that anyway with any OS that had previous use by another party. No telling what else lurks in that Windows installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect the program restores itself the same way it restores all other changes: by not allowing the deletion to *happen* in the first place.

As long as the program is active, you're not working directly on the real filesystem – all your changes, whether creations or deletions, are recorded elsewhere on the system as an "overlay" (either in memory or in a hidden location on the system drive), while the "base" system remains intact the whole time. Even if you try to delete the program itself, that too is only saved in the overlay.

Upon reboot, the overlay is simply thrown away and a new one started from the original base, which never actually lost any of the files and registry keys that you "deleted". (It's a bit similar to VM snapshots, only achieved from within the OS.)

Even "deleting" the program itself just records the deletion in the overlay and has no effect on the base system. The official uninstaller may work by requesting the overlay driver to disable itself; if you need to bypass this, you would need to remove the program *externally* (e.g. disable the driver through WinPE or remove the files using a Linux liveCD).

It's documented that [Windows SteadyState](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SteadyState) used to work this way; I don't know for sure whether third-party tools like Deep Freeze use the same approach, but it's highly likely, since it results in very fast "restores" (the program doesn't have to restore anything, it merely has to *delete* the overlay).

SteadyState used the "Windows Disk Protection" feature integrated to Windows. I don't know whether third-party programs use WDP, but more likely they achieve the same thing through custom filter drivers, as WDP now seems to be no longer supported.

Linux similarly has overlayfs/unionfs/aufs special filesystems. Nearly all Linux "LiveCDs" use overlayfs for their root filesystem (the `/`), by combining a read-only SquashFS base image from the CD/USB with an in-memory overlay – and if you use the "persistence" feature of the LiveCD, that only causes the overlay to be stored on a separate image on the USB stick, while still using the same read-only base.